# How to create a dynamic hover map with changing images

Tags: image, dictionary, hover, area, coords

I am building a map navigation for a client and am stuck! I have built the map using  and coords and all is fine. However I now need for each region to change colour when you hover over it.

I have done this before with simple sliced-up PNGs in Photoshop but because of the complexity of the map and overlapping items this isn't an option. I don't even know where to start - have tried some different tutorials and a lot of googling but can't find a good solution.

Here is my map so far: http://www.wiredcanvas.com/uploads/map/map.html

I want it so that when you click on a region it will turn a different colour - and I may also add a tooltip if necessary.

Any advice or help as to where I should go from here very gratefully received!!

Thank-you in advance

Alice